# Merge two arrays from a given index - PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, merge, append

I am wondering if there is an easy way to 'append' new elements to an array, but not at the end

Imagine I have a vector

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

I want to append a new vector

```
b = np.array([1,1,1,1])
```

to a, starting from element 3 so that the new array would be

```
c = np.array([1,2,3,5,6,7,1])
```

that is the last 3 elements of array a are resulting from a+b while the new element just belong to C

Any ideas?

THX

I tried just append!

Comment: "that is the last 3 elements of array a are resulting from a+b while the new element just belong to C" What you are describing isn't really an "append" operation.

Comment: I tried to change the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @user Please clarify the logic behind what you're trying to do. What's the connection between the arrays you start with ([1,2,3,4,5,6] and [1,1,1,1]) and the array you end up with [1,2,3,5,6,7,1]? My best guess at the logic here is that you want to find `[1,2,3,4+1,5+1,6+1,0+1]`. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

Using numpy with [`pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html):

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
b = np.array([1,1,1,1])
# or
# a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
# b = [1,1,1,1]

n = 3
extra = len(b)-len(a)+n

c = np.pad(a, (0, extra))
c[n:] += b
```

Output:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 1])
```

Comment: OP has since clarified that the question is indeed about numpy arrays